# Encrypt python script

Tags: python, encryption

I need to create some python script for a client, that must run in his servers. Since they don't pay for the source code, my boss is asking for a way to encrypt the scripts, to avoid that the client can read them and copy/paste the code for other purposes.

Is there a way to encrypt a python script and running it in encrypted format?

Comment: maybe make a bundle with pyinstaller then?

Comment: https://storage-admin.com/how-convert-python-scripts-to-binary-files/